# Unable to override click events to anchor tag from a user created function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I don't know how to explain my situation, please edit my question if you can explain it more clearly.

I am able to override click events of anchor tag from window.load or document.ready but the problem comes when I am trying it from a user created function.

My JavaScript code is:

```
$('#up').click(function(){
$('#Vote').html("<div id=\"aniDiv\" style=\"background:green;height:25px;width:80px;position:absolute;float:left\" class=\"base\"></div><div class=\"overlay\"><a style=\"text-decoration:none;color:black\" id='unvote' href=\"#\">You upvoted. Click to take vote back.</a></div>");

    $("#aniDiv").animate({width:"10px"});
        $("#Vote").width("350px");
        attachUnvote();
});
    $('#down').click(function(){
    $('#Vote').html("<div id=\"aniDiv\" style=\"background:red;height:25px;width:50px;position:absolute;float:left\" class=\"base\"></div><div class=\"overlay\"><a style=\"text-decoration:none;color:black\" id='unvote' href=\"#\">You downvoted. Click to take vote back.</a></div>");

    $("#aniDiv").animate({width:"10px"});
        $("#Vote").width("350px");

    attachUnvote()
    });

function attachUnvote()
{
    $('#unvote').click(function(){
    $('#Vote').html("<a style='text-decoration:none;background-color:green;padding:3px;color:white;' id='up' href='#'>Up</a><a style='text-decoration:none;background-color:red;padding:3px;color:white' id='down' href='#'>Down</a>");
});
}
```

My objective is that after `attachUnvote()` function sets the HTML of #Vote element, then it should call the code just above `attachUnvote()` function. I tried to enclose the code above it in another function and called that function in `attachUnvote()` but its not working.

You can find Live Demo, HTML and CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/aishwaryashivapareek/xV3x8/

Comment: The indentation makes your code difficult to follow, which will dissuade people from trying to understand it.

Comment: Looks like you do not have fully working code.. Missing the attachvote method for starters.. Also use classes whenever possible. Avoid inline styles

Comment: ignore `attachVote()` as it meant to contain the code just above `attachUnvote()`. You just tell me how to re-override click events of #sup and #opp elements after `attachUnvote()` adds html to #Vote.

Comment: Looks like you might be working with duplicate id's which will be a problem. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event delegation is the way to go.

I might be nitpicking here but this also makes coding fun instead of falling into a spaghetti mess. Have some pointers which would make your life easier.

Avoid inline styles. use classes instead. (Would help in separation of concerns)
Use functions to avoid repetitive code.

**HTML**

```
<div id='Vote' style="margin:0">
    <a class="p-small bg-green" id='up' href="#">Up</a>
    <a class="p-small bg-red" id='down' href="#">Down</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family:'segoe ui'
}
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.base {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
/* Default styling for anchors */
 a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
}
.p-small {
    padding: 3px;
}
.bg-red {
    background-color:red;
}
.bg-green {
    background-color:green;
}
.black {
    color: black;
}
#aniDiv {
    height: 25px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var $defaultDiv =  "<a class='p-small bg-green' id='up' href='#'>Up</a>" 
                 + "<a class='p-small bg-red' id='down' href='#'>Down</a>",
    $animatedDiv = "<div id='aniDiv' class='base {{bg}}'></div>"
                +  "<div class='overlay'>"
+  "<a class='black' id='unvote' href='#'>You {{vote}}. Click to take vote back.</a></div>";

$('#Vote').on('click', '#up', function() {
    animateDiv("bg-green", true);
});

$('#Vote').on('click', '#down', function() {
    animateDiv("bg-red", false);
});

$('#Vote').on('click', '#unvote', function() {
    $('#Vote').html($defaultDiv);
});

function animateDiv(bgColor, upVoted) {
    $('#Vote').html($animatedDiv.replace("{{bg}}", bgColor)
                    .replace("{{vote}}", upVoted ? "upvoted" : "downvoted"));
    $("#aniDiv").animate({
        width: "10px"
    });
    $("#Vote").width("350px");
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xV3x8/3/)**

Comment: thanks Sushanth, krhorst code worked but it was not working on my deployment machine. But your code worked and also looks generalized.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva . Glad to have helped :)

Comment: can you please tell me why this code is not working in Google Chrome after I deployed on my website?

Comment: Here is the question I asked about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931292/jquery-code-not-working-in-google-chrome-after-adding-it-to-main-website?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid having to attach and unattach these event handlers by using a delegated event handler on the #Vote wrapper.

Your updated code would look like this:

```
$('#Vote').on('click','#up',function(){
    $('#Vote').html("<div id=\"aniDiv\" style=\"background:green;height:25px;width:80px;position:absolute;float:left\" class=\"base\"></div><div class=\"overlay\"><a style=\"text-decoration:none;color:black\" id='unvote' href=\"#\">You upvoted. Click to take vote back.</a></div>");
    $("#aniDiv").animate({width:"10px"});
    $("#Vote").width("350px");
});

$('#Vote').on('click','#down',function(){
    $('#Vote').html("<div id=\"aniDiv\" style=\"background:red;height:25px;width:50px;position:absolute;float:left\" class=\"base\"></div><div class=\"overlay\"><a style=\"text-decoration:none;color:black\" id='unvote' href=\"#\">You downvoted. Click to take vote back.</a></div>");
    $("#aniDiv").animate({width:"10px"});
    $("#Vote").width("350px");
});

$('#Vote').on('click','#unvote',function(){
    $('#Vote').html("<a style='text-decoration:none;background-color:green;padding:3px;color:white;' id='up' href='#'>Up</a><a style='text-decoration:none;background-color:red;padding:3px;color:white' id='down' href='#'>Down</a>");
});
```