# JQuery code not working in Google Chrome after adding it to main website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

My JQuery code is not working in Google Chrome when I am testing it on main website but its working in IE. Also when I am testing it in JSFiddle using Google Chrome, it's working there. Here is my complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/xV3x8/3/

You can check my this question: [Unable to override click events to anchor tag from a user created function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920254/unable-to-override-click-events-to-anchor-tag-from-a-user-created-function) if you want to know what is the motive of this code.

JQuery code:

```
var $defaultDiv =  "<a class='p-small bg-green' id='up' href='#'>Up</a>" 
                 + "<a class='p-small bg-red' id='down' href='#'>Down</a>",
    $animatedDiv = "<div id='aniDiv' class='base {{bg}}'></div>"
                +  "<div class='overlay'>"
+  "<a class='black' id='unvote' href='#'>You {{vote}}. Click to take vote back.</a></div>";

$('#Vote').on('click', '#up', function() {
    animateDiv("bg-green", true);
});

$('#Vote').on('click', '#down', function() {
    animateDiv("bg-red", false);
});

$('#Vote').on('click', '#unvote', function() {
    $('#Vote').html($defaultDiv);
});

function animateDiv(bgColor, upVoted) {
    $('#Vote').html($animatedDiv.replace("{{bg}}", bgColor)
                    .replace("{{vote}}", upVoted ? "upvoted" : "downvoted"));
    $("#aniDiv").animate({
        width: "10px"
    });
    $("#Vote").width("350px");
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: please check the console of google-chorme browser for javascript error...

Comment: Console is not showing any error.

Comment: If there is no issue in the console, there must be some other issue with the script on the `main site` perhaps you can give the address for people to look at?

Comment: is code wrapped in a ready handler? fiddle does this for you

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I can't share the website as my company rules doesn't allow it. It's actually password protected site.

Comment: @charlietfl I am actually calling a function from `$(document).ready` that fuction in return calls a function containing code just above `animateDiv()`

Comment: ok - that's unfortunate, another way forward then is to break the `main site` down to bare basics by commenting out everything unnecessary and unrelated, making sure it works then, and the you can start adding those scripts/elements back in until you hit the error.  Tedious but will give you a better idea of what's wrong.

Comment: does element exist when code is run? maybe you need event delegation

Comment: @charlietfl element must be there, as it is running successfully in IE.

Comment: it may be jquery conflict.

Comment: First of all thanks to everyone for responding to my question. I finally found the solution. I posted it as answer. But I don't know the reason. Please if anybody can tell me it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. All I need to do is to remove `href='#'` from my links. I don't know why this is not working in Chrome. If anybody can explain me it will be a great help. `href='#'` I think usually added to activate links for anchors that use JavaScript function on click, but that can be done using CSS `cursor: pointer`.